# How to set up email for document libraries without affecting existing email addresses

Tags: document-library, email, incoming-email, smtp, exchange

My goal is simple - have SharePoint document libraries to be able to receive emails, and I try to get this done as minimal as possible without affecting other features or services.

In Central Administration, I enabled "`Sites on this server to receive Email`". And picked "no" for Directory Management Services. Where I got stuck is the "`E-mail server display address`" field.

What should I put for this field? To be honest I'm not really sure about the mechanism behind the entire email receiving feature. I mean, are we supposed to use our organization's email domain for this? Or this could be spoofed to whatever we pick? Let's say our organization have the email domain of `@my.org`, do I have to use that? Or can I use `@foobar.com`? or a sub-domain of our organization domain such as `@email.my.org`?

Assume we could only use the domain for our organization. When I create the email address for the document library, what should I put for that email address? Would SharePoint actually create a valid email to Active Directory? If we could put anything for the email of document library, let's say `foo-bar@my.org`, what if there is already a employee using that as a valid email? Wouldn't that cause a conflict? Would they (the person and the SharePoint doc library) both receive the email?

As you can tell I'm not sure how the back end interacts with each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My organisation has the domain `myorg.com` and my email address is `something@myorg.com`. Our SharePoint farm uses the sub-domain `sp.myorg.com` and any email enabled lists will use `ListName@sp.myorg.com`.  Of course there is still the issue of duplicates if different sites have lists with the same name. A naming convention, for example incorporating the site name in the list email address `SiteA.ListA@sp.myorg.com`, might help reduce that risk.

Comment: Thank you teylyn, so if we create the new email, does there email automatically gets created in active directory or exchange as well?

Comment: If everything is set up correctly, you only need to email-enable the list/library and specify the email address in the list settings. It can then be used immediately. Nothing to be set up in Exchange or AD.